# How to dynamically bind event to command in WinRT without Reactive framework?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, system.reactive

I'm implementing modified version of Behavior for my Windows 8 app [according to this guide](http://www.be-init.nl/blog/12968/a-winrt-behavior-to-mimic-eventtocommand). It works except one place where the Reactive framework is required:

```csh
protected override void OnAttached()
{
  var evt = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(Event);
  if (evt != null)
  {
    Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(AssociatedObject, Event)
      .Subscribe(se => FireCommand());
  }
  base.OnAttached();
}
```

The question is simple, how to achieve similar funcitonality without the Reactive frmaework? I've browsed the source of of Rx that can be [obtained here](https://rx.codeplex.com/%E2%80%8E), but I'ts just too complicated to me.
I've also succeeded porting to code with the only problem that it work only for fixed type of EventHandler:

```csh
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    EventInfo evt = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(Event);
    if (evt != null)
    {
        AssignEvent<ItemClickEventHandler>(AssociatedObject, Event, FireCommand);
    }
    base.OnAttached();
}

protected void AssignEvent<T1>(object instance, string eventName, T1 handler)
{
    EventInfo runtimeEvent = instance.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(eventName);
    Func<T1, EventRegistrationToken> add = a => (EventRegistrationToken)runtimeEvent.AddMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { a });
    Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = a => runtimeEvent.RemoveMethod.Invoke(runtimeEvent, new object[] { a });

    WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler(add, remove, handler);
}
```

Any idea, how to make it dynamic so I don't have to use specific event handler "ItemClickEventHandler"? Note in classic .NET it' quite simple, but in WinRT I cannot use **Delegate.CreateDelegate(...)**

**Update**:
Thanks to **Brandon** I was able to finish the method, it now looks like this:

```csh
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    EventInfo evt = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(Event);
    if (evt != null)
    {
        MethodInfo addMethod = evt.AddMethod;
        MethodInfo removeMethod = evt.RemoveMethod;
        ParameterInfo[] addParameters = addMethod.GetParameters();
        Type delegateType = addParameters[0].ParameterType;
        Action<object, object> handler = (s, e) => FireCommand(e as RoutedEventArgs);
        MethodInfo handlerInvoke = typeof(Action<object, object>).GetRuntimeMethod("Invoke", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) });
        Delegate @delegate = handlerInvoke.CreateDelegate(delegateType, handler);

        Func<object, EventRegistrationToken> add = a => (EventRegistrationToken)addMethod.Invoke(AssociatedObject, new object[] { @delegate });
        Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = t => removeMethod.Invoke(AssociatedObject, new object[] { t });

        WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler(add, remove, handler);
    }
    base.OnAttached();
}
```

Now I can remove 800kB of Rx dlls, thanks again!

Comment: Any particular reason to remove the Rx code?  I thought there was a core Rx library that worked even on RT?

Comment: First of all I want to decrease the size of my app package to half and also I want to know, how this works internally.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you register the event handler via `WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler()`?  It is not hard to solve the problem if we can just call the `Add` and `Remove` methods of the EventInfo object.

Comment: First of all for using EventInfo.Add you need to know the target EventHandler type and second, when I tried to use it with the proper type: "Adding or removing event handlers dynamically is not supported on WinRT events."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trolled through the Rx source, and here is the important bit of functionality:

```
MethodInfo addMethod = eventInfo.GetAddMethod();
MethodInfo removeMethod = eventInfo.GetRemoveMethod();
var addParameters = addMethod.GetParameters();
var delegateType = addParameters[0].ParameterType;
Action<object, object> handler = (object sender, object eventArgs) => FireCommand();
MethodInfo handlerInvoke = typeof(Action<object, object>).GetMethod("Invoke");
Delegate delegate = handlerInvoke.CreateDelegate(delegateType, handler);

Func<EventRegistrationToken> add = a => (EventRegistrationToken)addMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { delegate });
Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = t => removeMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { t });
```

It looks like the important info is they are using [MethodInfo.CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194376%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: With some WinRT specific modifications I was able to make it work, thanks!